# Varnish Age is 0 (proxy via nginx to node app)

Tags: nginx, ssl, varnish

I'm trying to add varnish to an existing web stack but I can't seem to get a cached version of my pages back. I'd like to know I may be doing wrong.

This configuration works but I do **not** get a cached response back from varnish:

```
 1. Nginx is listening on port 443, request proxied to Varnish
 2. Varnish is listening on port 80, request proxied to Node App
 3. Successful Response
```

**What I've tried:**

`curl -kIL https://www.example.com`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
Set-Cookie: locale=en-ca; Path=/
Set-Cookie: locale=en-ca; Path=/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 161861
ETag: W/"27845-EcqEhuo8dduXo4rrAF4EfS6igbQ"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Wed, 18 Oct 2017 23:57:39 GMT
X-Varnish: 33476
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
```

For each subsequent request `Age:` is always `0`

**VCL for reference:**

```
vcl 4.0;
import std;

backend example {
    .host = "www.example.com";
    .port = "7600";
}

backend api {
    .host = "api";
    .port = "8080";
}

sub vcl_recv {

    # Remove the port from Host
    set req.http.Host = regsub(req.http.Host, ":[0-9]+", "");

    if (req.http.host ~ "www.example.com") {
        set req.backend_hint = example;
        std.log("hit example.com");
    }


    if (req.http.host ~ "^api") {
        set req.backend_hint = api;
        std.log("hit api");
    }

    if (req.http.User-Agent ~ "Amazon Route 53") {
        return (pass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions 1) Why aren't you using Nginx page caching? 2) Why can't Varnish talk directly to Nginx https? 3) Are you setting caching headers correctly? That tends to be pretty key with caching. Perhaps show the headers as they are at each layer.

Comment: 1. I was using it but wanted to try another implementation and see which performs better. 2. Varnish doesn't support SSL. 3. I've updated my answer with a curl command to include a cache header and it's response

Comment: You have a max cache age of 30 seconds, which seems short. I wonder if that's affecting the ability to cache, or testing of the caching. Is that curl direct to the source server, Nginx, or HAProxy? Probably best to show all of them.

Comment: Show us the vcl

Comment: @Tim that curl is against Nginx. If i issue it directly against node I don't get the varnish headers back and I can't issue SSL directly against varnish

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting things cached is presence of `Set-Cookie` header in your application response:

```
Set-Cookie: locale=en-ca; Path=/
Set-Cookie: locale=en-ca; Path=/
```

If you want to continue using Varnish and ensure it's caching things, you should update your application to set cookie only when necessary, as opposed to every page.

For multi-language websites it is best to rely on `Accept-Language:` request header and send `Vary` on the language rather than use cookies.

Comment: `curl -kIL -H 'Set-Cookie: locale=en-ca; Path=/' https://www.example.com` that curl command still does not change the age on second, third requests

Comment: Passing Set-Cookie to curl makes no sense. It's a header that is sent by backend. Not clients

Comment: for testing purposes, I added `unset req.http.Cookie;` into my example.com site block and varnish still isn't caching. any other information i can give you?

Comment: You wouldn't need those experiments if you looked at [builtin VCL](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/blob/4.1/bin/varnishd/builtin.vcl#L156) logic which makes it clear that Set-Cookie results in no caching. Furthermore, depending on where you unset it might not work and you have to do it twice, because you have **two** duplicate headers set. If you don't want to fix your app, I would say that Varnish isn't for you.